# Can I subclass elasticsearch-dsl's IpRange to be used by django-elasticsearch-dsl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, elasticsearch-dsl, python-class

How can one use the ip_range field type for CIDR notated IP addresses with [django-elasticsearch-dsl](https://github.com/django-es/django-elasticsearch-dsl)?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html#ip-range

I tried making a subclass but it results in a field mapping of "type": "text"

```
...
from django_elasticsearch_dsl.fields import DEDField
from elasticsearch_dsl.field import IpRange
...

class IpRangeField(DEDField, IpRange):
    """Subclass based on DedField and IpRange."""


@registry.register_document
class FeedDataDocument(Document):
    """FeedData elasticsearch."""
    ...
    ipaddress = IpRangeField()
    ...
```

Results in:

```
"mappings": {
  "_doc": {
    "properties": {
      "ipaddress": {
        "type": "text"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen all of your code, but I suggest that you first make certain that you are subclassing (or hooking and subclassing) correctly. Line by line, check your syntax and make certain that you are supplying to that correctly.

If you are in a Microsoft Windows system, you might (separately) also get a list of all open windows handles and try subclassing via one of those handles to verify that you are doing your subclassing correctly.

Do testing with some simple other program first to verify that you can read and intercept messages to and from a subclassed window.

Then I would suggest that you make certain that you can read or return from that which is subclassed a very simple value. In Windows if you subclass a window then you can get a handle to that window which you subclassed, unless you are subclassing an instance before a window handle has been assigned by the operating system (which is only a little a bit more complicated). For example, if you are subclassing a new tab in FireFox, then you get the pre-and-unassigned-window (I do not recall what it is called) that is to-be a FireFox tab which FireFox will incorporate quickly later into its one-and-only-one Window's handle, then you would do that before there is a handle assigned to that tab. If you have that situation of what you are after being assigned to a handle with other interrupting items, then that might be your problem. I did this years ago and got it to work, but I do not have time now find it and to post it here. But, you get the idea.

Then, after you have tested your subclassing on a simple program and have verified that you are doing it correctly and that you are obtaining the results correctly, then and only then after that test what you are talking about in this post.

Then, if you cannot get the desired results, it looks like django_elasticsearch_dsl is the problem and you should study that more.

ps: In case you are wondering why I post but do not reply to comments: My browser does not seem to support the "add a comment" on these Stack Overflow pages, so I can post but I cannot (until SO makes their pages more backward compatible sufficient for me) reply or comment beyond that. And, I found out yesterday that the email server that I had been using for this account is not working.